# Use NSCoding on a custom class with an array of an enums as a property

Tags: swift, enums, swift2, nscoding

I am trying to be able to serialize and decode a custom class. The class itself has a property which is an array of enums, like this:

(I've read how to use the raw value and serialize that but I haven't had any luck figuring out how to do it with an array like this).

```
enum WeekDays : String {

case Sunday     = "Sunday"
case Monday     = "Monday"
case Tuesday    = "Tuesday"
case Wednesday  = "Wednesday"
case Thursday   = "Thursday"
case Friday     = "Friday"
case Saturday   = "Saturday"
}

class User: NSObject, NSCoding {

var name     : String
var workDays : [WeekDays]

init(name: String, workDays: [WeekDays]) {

    self.name = name
    self.workDays = workDays
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
    //        self.workDays =  ???? 
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

    aCoder.encodeObject(self.name, forKey: "name")
//        aCoder.encodeObject(self.workDays, forKey: "workDays") 
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about following the idea of Matt Neuburg presented in book
"iOS 9 Programming Fundamentals with Swift" inside chapter "Object Types":

According to him, an elegant fix (suggested in a WWDC 2015 video) is to teach NSCoder, the class of coder, what to do when the forKey: argument is an WeekDays instead of a String. So in an extension, you could overload the encodeObject:forKey: method:

```
extension NSCoder {
    func encodeObject(objv: AnyObject?, forKey key: WeekDays) {
        self.encodeObject(objv, forKey:key.rawValue)
    }
}
```

I would then try to iterate over an array of WeekDays and glue all needed values as one long String like: "Sunday|Monday|..."

Comment: I think I'm just going to use the bottom part of your answer and make a string that I can re-assemble when it's decoded.